"Not many can say that is there."
A 105 year old lady is telling about her feelings. She says:

I mean I have lived here 105 years. Not many can say that is there. No. 105 year.

BBC- elderly lived in the same house for 105 years (see:2:40-2:47)
I checked the subtitles. If not wrong, this is what she said. And I couldn't quite understand what she meant by ".....Not many can say that is there....". As a non-native speaker, it made me think of 2 meanings: Does she mean;

I have lived quite a long life. Not many people can reach such a long lifetime of 105 years.

OR

I don't look my age. Not many people can say there are actually 105 years on my face.

Thanks.

In modern parlance innit. People often do not speak grammatically. Neither of your  suggested meanings is relevant (although she may also have said that). The quote is about how long she has lived in that house.
